# Download parquet file from ADL Gen2 using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying below powershell command to download parquet file from ADL Gen 2 to local system.
Below is the code snippet

```html
#this appid has access to ADL
[string] $AppID  = "bbb88818-aaaa-44fb-q2345678901y" 
 [string] $TenantId  = "ttt88888-xxxx-yyyy-q2345678901y"
 [string] $SubscriptionName  = "Sub Sample"
 [string] $LocalTargetFilePathName  = "D:\MoveToModern"


Write-Host "AppID = " $AppID
Write-Host "TenantId = " $TenantId
Write-Host "SubscriptionName = " $SubscriptionName
Write-Host "AzureDataLakeAccountName = " AzureDataLakeAccountName
Write-Host "AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath = " $AzureDataLakeSrcFilePath
Write-Host "LocalTargetFilePathName = " $LocalTargetFilePathName



#this is the access key of the appid
$AccessKeyValue = "1234567=u-r.testabcdefaORYsw5AN5"

$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKeyValue -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppID, $azurePassword)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId

Get-AzureRmSubscription

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName  | Set-AzureRmContext
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "/Test/Partner/Account/" -Blob "Account.parquet" -Destination "D:\MoveToModern"
```

But I am getting below error
[image]

May be we have to set the storage context. Can you please let me know how to set the storage context with the service principal. (I have app id & app key of service principal. W.r.t ADL Gen2 source, I just have the path details. Source team has provided access to service principal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download files from Azure Data Lake Gen2, I suggest you use PowerShell module [**`Az.Storage`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#download-from-a-directory). Meanwhile, regarding how to implement it with a service principal, you have two choices.

**1. Use Azure  RABC Role**

If you use Azure  RABC Role, you need to assign  the special role(**Storage Blob Data Reader**) to the sp.

For example

```
$AppID  = "" 
$AccessKeyValue  = ""
$TenantId=""
$SubscriptionName  = ""
#1. Assign role at the storage account level
#please use owner account to login
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $TenantId -Subscription $SubscriptionName
New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId $AppID  -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Reader" `
      -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"

# download

$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKeyValue -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppID, $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId -Subscription $SubscriptionName

$AzureDataLakeAccountName  = "testadls05"

$ctx =New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AzureDataLakeAccountName -UseConnectedAccount 

$LocalTargetFilePathName  = "D:\test.parquet"
$filesystemName="test"
$path="2020/10/28/test.parquet"
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $path -Destination $LocalTargetFilePathName
```

[image]

2. Use Access control lists

If you use the method, to grant a security principal read access to a file, you'll need to give the security principal Execute permissions to the container, and to each folder in the hierarchy of folders that lead to the file.

For example

[image]

```
$AppID  = "" 
$AccessKeyValue  = ""
$TenantId=""


$azurePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccessKeyValue -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred           = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppID, $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $TenantId


$AzureDataLakeAccountName  = "testadls05"
$ctx =New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AzureDataLakeAccountName -UseConnectedAccount 

$filesystemName="test"
$path="2020/10/28/test.parquet"
$LocalTargetFilePathName  = "D:\test1.parquet"
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $path -Destination $LocalTargetFilePathName
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell